# Need help changing file size allowed to upload on attachment form

Tags: php, forms, attachment, email-attachments

When I try to attach a file to my upload form, it gives me this error:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 26990378 bytes)in /home/content/j/o/h/johnmunro/html/upload/include/class.phpmailer.php on line 1238

and here is the line of code on 1238 that is apparently causing this issue. can someone help me.

```
 /**
* Encodes string to requested format. Returns an
* empty string on failure.
* @access private
* @return string
*/
function EncodeString ($str, $encoding = 'base64') {
$encoded = '';
switch(strtolower($encoding)) {
  case 'base64':
    /* chunk_split is found in PHP >= 3.0.6 */
    $encoded = chunk_split(base64_encode($str), 76, $this->LE);
    break;
  case '7bit':
  case '8bit':
    $encoded = $this->FixEOL($str);
    if (substr($encoded, -(strlen($this->LE))) != $this->LE)
      $encoded .= $this->LE;
    break;
  case 'binary':
    $encoded = $str;
    break;
  case 'quoted-printable':
    $encoded = $this->EncodeQP($str);
    break;
  default:
    $this->SetError($this->Lang('encoding') . $encoding);
    break;
}
return $encoded;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The error means that php requires more memory to run.

To increase allocated memory size to php you have to call :
**ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');**
at the starting of your script(preferably).
Replace 256 with the amount of memory you need.

**UPDATE**

You should also work on memory optimization techniques so that php does not require vast amounts of memory to execute.

Please go through:

Tips to prevent running out of memory:http://v1.srcnix.com/2010/02/10/7-tips-to-prevent-php-running-out-of-memory/

PHP memory and performance manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.performance-considerations.php

Comment: so that small string of code should fix my issue? there's no need to do anything else? what would I need the links you provided for just incase I need more?

Comment: for some reason it gave me this error: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /home/content/j/o/h/johnmunro/html/upload/include/fgcontactform.php on line 30

Comment: Please share the error detsails. i.e message code etc